# Build element(s) if less than 9 exist

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm building the portfolio of my site.  I want to show off a 3x3 grid of my work.  I'm trying to write a javascript code that will render gray blocks as placeholders so that the total of squares (including the shots) is **ALWAYS** 9.

**The goal:**

[image]

**My code:**

```
function inventBlank() {

    // define variables
    var shot = document.getElementById('shot'),
        a = document.getElementById('a'),
        div = document.createElement('div');

    // insertAfter function
    function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }

    // if existing shots is less than 9...
    if (shot < 9) {
        // render gray boxes until 9
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.className = "shot";
            div.insertAfter(a, div);
            // insert new element "div" after "a"
        }
    }
}

inventBlank();
// call anonymous function
```

I try to use this, but the console says it's an anonymous function!

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HQGg4/24/embedded/result/)

Basically, it's supposed to render gray blocks after the span.  It will accomplish this by generating a div with the name of div.

I'm pretty sure the for loop is invalid! :(

Comment: So basically, you're getting one single element, as ID's are unique and that's all getElementById gets, and it gets a HTML element as an object, not a number, then you do `if ( single_element_object > 9 ) ` and that doesn't work !

Comment: You might want to learn a bit more about DOM elements: http://quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html .

Comment: if you always want 9 boxes (regardless of whether it is filled with a shot or not), why not just hard code in 9 boxes and dynamically fill them from an array of shots?

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using Jekyll.  I don't know how that would be done.  But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: you could dynamically fill the box with either a for loop, or using jquery $.each()

Comment: try this: http://jsfiddle.net/p1xelarchitect/wZ6vg/

Comment: FYI, I imported a jQuery library.  if you want to use this method, you will just have to add the following to your <head> section:
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some fix to do , but can be a starting point

http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/bzVQ6/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <style>
        .wrapper {
            width: 960px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        img, .shot {
            width: 292px;
            height: 219px;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px;
            background: #eee;
        }

        .clearFix{
            clear:both;

        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <section class="main" id="main">

        </section>
    </div>

    <script>
        var shot = function (src) {
            this.src = src;
        };

        var shots = [];

        shots.push(new shot('https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/332776/screenshots/1567549/weather-dribbble.jpg'));
        shots.push(new shot('https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/332776/screenshots/1588565/safari-yosemite-dribbble.jpg'));
        shots.push(new shot('https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/332776/screenshots/1573950/browsers.jpg'));
        shots.push(new shot('https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/332776/screenshots/1546946/blackclock-dribbble.jpg'));
        shots.push(new shot(''));
        shots.push(new shot(''));
        shots.push(new shot(''));
        shots.push(new shot(''));
        shots.push(new shot(''));

        function addShot(target, source) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.setAttribute('class', 'shot');
            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute('src', source.src);
            div.appendChild(img);
            target.appendChild(div);
        }
        function appendClear(target) {

            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.setAttribute('class', 'clearFix');
            target.appendChild(div);
        }

        var target = document.getElementById('main');


        for (var i = 0; i < shots.length ; i++) {
            if(i >0 && i % 3 == 0){
                appendClear(target);
            }
            addShot(target, shots[i]);
        }


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```